# call more than one methode by current thread

Tags: java, multithreading

suppose we have these classes and read the comments

```
class Work {
void doWork(){  }
void commit(){}       
}
class MyRunable implements Runnable {
run(){
   Work  work=new Work();
   work.doWork();
//i can't write work.commit() here, because sometimes i want Thread runs both methods       
 //and sometimes runs only doWork()
 }
}
class Tasks{
main(){
MyRunable myRunable=new MyRunable();
Thread t=new Thread(myRunable);
t.start();
//suppose now i need to call commit() method by the same thread (t)
//how can i do that 
}
}
```

also i don't want to use constructor to determine if i want to call both method or not

Comment: @Starx: I think he means `work.commit();`

Comment: Do you call `work.doWork()` in a loop? If you don't the `run` method will finish, and the thread will become `TERMINATED`, and you will not be able to call anything from that thread.

Comment: 'sometimes i want Thread runs both methods and sometimes runs only doWork' how do you want to signal the thread so that it can choose?  Typically, such requirements are met by queueing tasks.  A task can contain one method, or both, or some flag/enum/set to control what is run.  You can submit such a task to a queue upon which your one thread is waiting, or to a threadpool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a thread pool with a single thread and keep enqueuing methods as needed:

```
class Tasks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final Work work = new Work();
        exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    work.doWork();
                }
            });
        // later
        exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    work.commit();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

This way, both methods will be executed in a sequence by the same thread, but separately.

Comment: thanks....this is exactly what i want...but if i want to make another thread(new one) which may do something else(invoke only doWork())

Comment: @user1361554: You could use a normal `Thread` like you did initially, or a different `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Btw, don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem. That's an important part of using SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter to your class `MyRunnable`. Call this parameter "runingMode". It could be an enum:

```
enum RunningMode {
    DO_WORK {
        public void work(Work work) {
             work.doWork();
        }
    },
    COMMIT {
        public void work(Work work) {
             work.commit();
        }
    };
    public abstract void work();
}
```

Now your class `MyRunnable` should have list of modes:

```
class MyRunable implements Runnable {
    private Collection<RunningMode> modes;
    MyRunable(Collection<RunningMode> modes) {
         this.modes = modes;
    }
}
```

Implement `run()` method as following:

```
  Work  work=new Work();
  for (RunningMode mode : modes) {
        mode.work(work);
  }
  work.doWork();
```

Create instance of your class passing to it the mode you currently need:

```
MyRunable myRunable=new MyRunable(Arrays.asList(RunningMode.DO_WORK, RunningMode.COMMIT));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anonymous class.

```
final boolean condition = ...
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Work work=new Work();
    work.doWork();
    if(condition)
       work.commit();
}});
t.start();
```

Comment: This assumes you know beforehand if the second method should be executed or not, right?